# How to retrieve selected value of combobox (not text)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, combobox

I've been making a little app to do some user account creations in AD, but I seem to be stuck with my ComboBox.

Currently in my project there's a method to add items to the specific ComboBox:

```
private void AddAccessBox(string name, string value)
    {
        ComboboxItem newitem = new ComboboxItem();
        newitem.Text = name;
        newitem.Value = value;
        accessLevelBox.Items.Add(newitem);
    }
```

To add an item to the ComboBox:

```
AddAccessBox("Standard User", "SSLVPN,anothergroup,andanother");
```

For some ungodly reason I can't work out how to get the Value of the selected item, SelectedValue and SelectedItem both are returning "Standard User".

[image]

I'm sure there's something tiny that i'm missing, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assigned a `ComboboxItem` instance to the `Items` collection of the ComboBox, so a ComboboxItem is returned by `SelectedItem` (or `SelectedValue`):

```
ComboboxItem item = accessLevelCombobox.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem;

if (item != null && item.Value == "SSLVPN,anothergroup,andanother")
{
}
```

Comment: Wow, you are really in a hurry... As a note, you usually access the SelectedItem property instead of SelectedValue, unless you've also set SelectedValuePath.

Comment: @Clemens - added new answer you OP can take latest one only ....doesnt mis lead him...I am working on angular project and answering on SO side by side ...

Comment: @Clemens - correct me if i am wrong ..but there is no databinding done by OP and in that case both will return same value ....

Comment: "there is no databinding done by OP"  why is it relevant for an answer? Anyway, no worries, *now* your answer is correct.

Comment: @Clemens - ok. actully i do answer on SO to increase knowldege and to get info where I am worng and good part is there is people who correct me..so for that i just asking , may i am wrong that might be case

Answer (score 0):

Broader answer, to demonstrate the whole combo process from fill up to use. Hopefully helpful.

Getting data from "users" table in "users.db" SQLite database ( with columns UserDomainName, UserInitials )

Values in the table

```
UserInitials | UserDomainName
-------------+---------------
AB           | Anthony.Boo
EB           | Etore.Buggati
```

C# code ( for example in "onLoad" of the form ) :

```
// Creating new datatable
DataTable DtTbl = new DataTable();

// Connecting to DB and filling the datatable
using (SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\users.db;Mode=ReadOnly"))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqliteDataReader reader = new SqliteCommand(@"SELECT * FROM users;", conn).ExecuteReader();
    
    // Loading the data from DB to the DataTable
    DtTbl.Load(reader);
    
    // Adding Rows - so I have in the table one empty one - the default is empty in this case
    DtTbl.Rows.Add();
    
    // Sorting the values in data table
    DtTbl.DefaultView.Sort = "UserInitials ASC";
}
```

Defining the use of the data for the combo:

```
this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "UserInitials";
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "UserDomainName";
this.comboBox1.DataSource = DtTbl;
```

The combo will display for the user:

```
|       |- the default
| AB    |
| EB    |
```

Use in the code:

```
// Handle the selection
private void comboBoxMu_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboboxtest();
}

// Some action 
private void comboboxtest() 
{

    MessageBox.Show("You selected in this combobox: " +  comboBoxMu.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("The value used in code is : " +  comboBoxMu.SelectedValue.ToString());
     

    if (comboBoxMu.SelectedValue.ToString() == "")
    {
        //Selected 'default' --> use this value '' ;
    } 

    if (comboBoxMu.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Anthony.Boo")
    {
        //Selected 'AB' --> use this value 'Anthony.Boo' ;
    } 

}
```

If you click on AB - visible result will be :

```
You selected in this combobox : AB

The value used in code is : Anthony.Boo
```